# Averaging the Results of Query in a Separate Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have the following query and get the following results, what I want is a column the right which averages only then values. In this example each would show 25.8:

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN LEFT(WORKORDER_LOT_ID,1) = 'A' 
            THEN '20' + RIGHT(WORKORDER_LOT_ID,2)
        WHEN LEFT(WORKORDER_LOT_ID,1) = 'J' 
            THEN '30' + RIGHT(WORKORDER_LOT_ID,2)
        ELSE ''
    END AS Serial_Number,
    SUM(HOURS_WORKED) AS Total_Hours
FROM
    LABOR_TICKET
WHERE  
    WORKORDER_BASE_ID LIKE '23765%'
    AND WORKORDER_LOT_ID IN ('A43', 'A44', 'A45', 'A46', 'A47', 'A48', 
                             'J43', 'J44', 'J45', 'J46', 'J47', 'J48')
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN LEFT(WORKORDER_LOT_ID,1) = 'A' THEN '20' + RIGHT(WORKORDER_LOT_ID,2)
        WHEN LEFT(WORKORDER_LOT_ID,1) = 'J' THEN '30' + RIGHT(WORKORDER_LOT_ID,2)
        ELSE ''
    END;
```

Result of query:

```
Serial_Number Total_Hours
---------------------------
2043       43.97
2044       31.99
2045       42.88
2046       29.80
2047       10.97
2048       18.02
3043       8.13
3044       38.53
3045       25.73
3046       31.99
3047       16.79
3048       11.20
```

I've tried playing around with subqueries but I didn't get the results I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function `AVG() OVER ()`. Note that window functions are always calculated *after* normal aggregation, so you can do `AVG(SUM(...)) OVER (...)`

You can also put the complex `CASE` into an `APPLY` so you don't need to repeat it

```sql
SELECT
  v.Serial_Number,
  SUM(l.HOURS_WORKED) AS Total_Hours,
  AVG(SUM(l.HOURS_WORKED)) OVER () AS Average_Hours
FROM LABOR_TICKET l
CROSS APPLY ((
    CASE
    WHEN LEFT(l.WORKORDER_LOT_ID,1) = 'A' THEN '20' + RIGHT(l.WORKORDER_LOT_ID,2)
    WHEN LEFT(l.WORKORDER_LOT_ID,1) = 'J' THEN '30' + RIGHT(l.WORKORDER_LOT_ID,2)
    ELSE ''
    END
)) AS v(Serial_Number)
WHERE l.WORKORDER_BASE_ID LIKE '23765%'
  AND l.WORKORDER_LOT_ID IN
   ('A43','A44','A45','A46','A47','A48','J43','J44','J45','J46','J47','J48')
GROUP BY v.Serial_Number;
```

If you have integers then you need to convert to decimal first

```sql
  AVG(SUM(l.HOURS_WORKED) * 1.0) OVER () AS Average_Hours
```